# TinyPass WordPress PayWall Resource ID

Tags: php, wordpress

I have installed the official TinyPass plugin on my WordPress website. I have set up the PayWall configuration on TinyPass' website. The problem is I can't enter TinyPass' paywall resource ID in the WordPress plugin settings. I don't want to create a new paywall form the plugin. I want to use the one that I've alredy made on TinyPass' website. Any ideas what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Dimitar, 
Tinypass considers a "paywall ID" different than a "resource ID."
Be sure that you are finding the "Paywall ID" on the left hand margin of your http://dashboard.tinypass.com account.

Do not worry about creating a new paywall from Wordpress - it is not possible to do that.
If you have any questions, please email: support@tinypass.com

Source: I work at Tinypass

-Luke

Comment: So how can I add the paywall in WordPress through the plugin?